# Swift : One Navigation bar item

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uicontainerview

I'm new to swift and I have problem with navigation bar item.

I've :

**1 Button"post"**

**4 toolbar Items Text and Image and two others**

**4 Containers hocked up with 4 view controllers**

**Each toolbar item** hocked to **1 containers(view-controller)** and so on for the others.

> **My Question is How to make The post button switch view controller according to the post type ( image or text).**

[image]

Comment: I would create an action in the viewController, and depending on post type content, push the corresponding viewController? Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I want the button to post according to the viewcontroller ( text vc or img vc) if the users tap he text on toolbar then he can post text if he tap the image he can post image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track the action your ToolBar Item (Post) will have according with any situation you want to. But then you probably gonna use some booleans. Create a connection from Storyboard to its file class of type Action, not outlet. In the action method created, you can check if it is supposed to post text or image, like:

```
if shouldPostText{
    // post text
}else{
    // post image
}
```

The boolean value you can change when text/image buttons are pressed. Then create two segues in storyboard, both linking your UIViewController *to the view controller of text* and *to the view controller of image*. Name the segues differently (like seguetoText and segueToImage) and do  like:

```
if shouldPostText{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToText", sender: self)
}else{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToImage", sender: self)
}
```

I'm not quite sure of what you were asking for but it seems like was this.